# Synonyms for the meaning of the 'shrugging' gesture

Tags: synonyms, gestures

'Shrugging' is a gesture we make with our shoulders.  Now I'm not strictly looking for synonyms of the actual gesture of shoulder shrugging, but rather words that convey the same emotion as when someone shrugs.  Ideally, I'm looking for a verb.

I recognize there are many reasons to shrug: 2 main reasons being to say 'whatever' or to say 'I don't know'. I'm actually looking for both interpretations (it doesn't have to be one term for both).  Again, I'm looking for synonyms for the *meaning* of the gesture.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking for.  You say you're not looking for synonyms, but then you say you are "looking for synonyms for the gesture or conveyance of it"  You also say you want a verb but ask for "the emotion that is conveyed" (a noun).

Comment: ambivalence, apathy, indifference, resignation... all nouns.

Comment: "To convey the message 'I don't know'" is a definition for shrugging, right? I'm looking for other words that mean the same thing.

Comment: I edited it to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Edited to make it even clearer for potential answerers.  Please re-edit if I've gotten your intent wrong.

Comment: For the meaning 'whatever' in answer to a question might be **to dismiss** because, by shrugging your shoulders as a response, you actually dismiss the question as something you don't care about. I'll look for more later, if this looks like something you had in mind

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "***verbal shrug***" is pretty [popular and well established](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbal%20shrug&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbal%20shrug%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google nGram chart of "verbal shrug" rising steadily in recent decades]

In literature, it's often used to describe a sound a speaker has just made, or an emotion captured by his body language, without explicitly identifying the "shrug" in question. So it may be that this set phrase is used precisely because English lacks an established word or term which expresses what a shrug expresses.

I [dunno](http://www.crosswordnexus.com/clue/verbal-shrug).

---

<sub>The Italians are ahead of us on this one. *[Boh](https://books.google.com/books?id=RszKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA440&lpg=PA440&dq=%22a%20kind%20of%20verbal%20shrug%22&source=bl&ots=uijtLn2ZhL&sig=BPo3CYSmkflnkNZWjY5Av-0yo3U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GPo5Vf-mFZHlsASp-oGACA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwCA%23v=onepage&q=%22a%20kind%20of%20verbal%20shrug%22&f=false)*.</sub>

Comment: While the meaning is obvious, I have literally never hear of such an expression.

Comment: After reading your comment, just for kicks, I decided to compare how common [*verbal shrug* is vs *literally never heard*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbal+shrug%2C+literally+never+heard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbal%20shrug%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliterally%20never%20heard%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

'Dismissive' springs to mind...

Answer (score 0):

For the meaning of "I don't know", I can think of a few adjectives, but the only verb (phrase) I can think of is to **[plead ignorance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plead)**, which is to indicate that one does not know, which is what shrugging means in that context:

> Whenever Mary asked him which dress was more appropriate for their outing, John would routinely plead ignorance, shrugging silently as she frowned at him in annoyance.